# React Native: How to remove item fade in animation when scroll in FlatList

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am using FlatList for scrolling horizontally images.
on Android, when I scroll horizontally the items are appearing, but they appear with a fade-in animation.
how can I remove the animation?

```
  <FlatList 
      showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false} 
      initialNumToRender={5} 
      horizontal={true} 
      data={images}
      snapToAlignment={"start"} 
      snapToInterval={210}
      decelerationRate={"fast"}
      keyExtractor={(item) => item.key}
      renderItem={(item)=>renderImage(item,selectedImageHandler)}/>

const renderImage = (itemData:{ index:number, item:ImageProps}, selectedImageHandler:(index:number)=>void) => {  
  return (
      <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.8} onPress={()=>selectedImageHandler(itemData.index)}>
        <Image style={styles.image} source={{uri:itemData.item.key}}/>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    )
```

}

[image]

Comment: Try removing activeOpacity={0.8} and wrap your renderItem view in <View> tag

Comment: didnt work :(  .i removed the activeOpacity={0.8} and wrapped the render item with <View> and still getting this fade-in animations.

Comment: Hide initialNumToRender prop from flatlist

Comment: i removed initialNumToRender and still getting the fadein animation